# Can I fly with a gold bar?

Tags: air-travel, legal, hand-luggage

Can I fly with a [Good Delivery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good_Delivery) gold bar? I'll have the certificate that I have been given with it.

I have looked on Google and found nothing that suggests it's a prohibited item on an aircraft. It's below the weight I am allowed to carry in person. I'll be taking it to Moscow, flying from Heathrow with BA.

[image: Person carrying a gold bar]

Comment: You need help in carrying that?

Comment: You'd probably need to declare it on your customs form: http://eng.customs.ru/images/stories/site_content/files/english.pdf

Comment: Does gold count as a "negotiable instrument" for either UK/Rus?

Comment: i suggest you also wear a [bulletproof vest](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48536/can-i-wear-a-bulletproof-vest-while-traveling-on-british-airways-from-heathrow).

Comment: @CMaster - you do for the US per https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/322/~/importing-gold-coins,-medals,-and-bullion . Not sure about Russa / UK. Quick Google searches weren't fruitful but my guess would be yes if it counts as such in the US..

Comment: You should have no problems from customs as long as you can prove legitimacy but flying to about $450,000 in a highly negotiable security on your person seems kinda silly.

Comment: For what that bar is worth, I'd hire a bonded and insured delivery company to deliver it to my destination.

Comment: @henning I wish my boss was smart enough to go with my idea: turning the gold bar into thin metal plates and stuff my vest with them, endless advantages. Easier for the security guys, no issues with luggage people, I would feel 100% secure that bullets can't get to me ... etc

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to walk into a bank and ask *them* to procure a gold bar, given a wire transfer? Then nobody has to fly anywhere.

Comment: Not sure how soft gold metal disks will make you 100% bullet proof, but could ya let us know how this works out? It sounds a lot like the intro to a Guy Richie movie

Comment: Reminder to test your gold bars are actually solid, as there's been quite a few cases of fake bars that are full of tungsten

Comment: @Johnny I don't trust them, they might replace it with a fake one and I am no gold expert.

Comment: Here's a funny story about security check with a Nobel Price (which is made of gold). http://blogs.scientificamerican.com/observations/what-it-s-like-to-carry-your-nobel-prize-through-airport-security/

Comment: [Pray](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49738/can-aircrew-order-me-not-to-stand-in-the-aisle) that nobody steals that, if they allow you to!

Comment: This was entertaining to read, but the "wish my boss was smart enough to melt a bar into disks so I could shove them down my vest and be secure bullets can't get me" gave its tongue-in-cheek'ness away.

Comment: So [it was not a laptop bag after all](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50299/are-there-any-laws-that-prevent-reserving-two-adjacent-seats-for-one-person-for#comment99775_50299).

Comment: Looking at all the question you've posted, both here and on security.stackexchange.com, one really starts to  wonder what business you're in !

Comment: @Ant [an other smart person](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/47019/isnt-it-less-secure-to-use-something-you-are-for-authentication#comment76206_47038)

Comment: I would point out that transferring items of currency into Russia given the current sanctions could very well get you into trouble on the way *out* of the country. Talk to a lawyer.

Comment: It probably doesn't matter to the gold bar's owner, given what you're being asked to do, but from what I've read, the "Good Delivery" label requires a [Chain of Integrity](http://www.afecustodial.com/chain-of-integrity/), which would be broken when you transport it (unless you're actually working for a secure transport company, which seems unlikely given the question).  So it may be *a* gold bar, but it wouldn't be a *Good Delivery* gold bar any more.

Comment: @MichaelT: The amount of trouble you may get for trying to circumvent the embargo is nothing compared to the carrier's trouble when _anyone_ in the streets in Moscow figures out you have a gold bar in your pocket (I know people who were beaten to cripples _for a camera_). Or, for that matter, the trouble with the russian-mafia owner of that gold bar who will most probably feed you to his dogs if you let it happen that someone steals it.

Comment: You are flying it to Moscow, so you might get some scrutiny at heathrow from customs as they might think you're trying to violate the EU financial sanctions against Russia.
Seriously though if your boss is too cheap to pay for a bonded courier for his gold bullion, He deserves whatever bad happens to his cargo. I Imagine though that your boss wants to avoid a bonded courier as this transfer is a little shady. If that's the case I'd get the hell out of there if i were you.

Comment: Of course, these days, this is restricted in one way or another in many countries. Naturally the exact answer depends on which country you are flying from/to. But in general almost all countries now have **a limit on the amount of cash** you can carry in or out, or if not a limit a declaration must be made, and it will potentially be confiscated if you don't do that. And of course, many have included gold in that calculation. There are many QA about it, even on this site.

Comment: It probably shouldn't be allowed in carry-on, just because of it's sheer density. I wonder how hard it would be to throw it through a wall.

Comment: @o0'. Just do the praying in the seat, [not in the aisle](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/49738/41775).

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Maybe not exactly the answer to your question, but according to [this site](http://www.rusimpex.ru/index1.htm?varurl=Content_e/Custom/Poshlin/index.htm) (see Section XIV, Chapter 71, HS code 7108131000), Russia imposes a 20% customs duty on the importation of gold bars.  So unless you have 5.3 million rubles on hand to pay the customs duty (or can break off a fifth of the bar), expect the customs officers to hold on to your gold bar until you come up with the money.  Be sure to get a receipt!

Comment: Can I pay by card?

Comment: @User: I don't know.  Does your credit card even have a limit that high?

Comment: Not mine, it belongs to the person who owns the gold bar, I am just the transporter

Comment: @User: Oh, the plot thickens.  I bet you'll get lots of questions from Russian customs about the owner.  Honestly, I have nothing resembling direct knowledge or experience of this situation, I'm just sharing information I found.  I really think you ought to get advice from a professional (probably a Russian lawyer, at least; yes this will cost money) before undertaking this journey.  With the amount of money at stake, I'd be very uncomfortable just relying on the advice of random people from the Internet.

Comment: we don't want to draw attention, I don't want to become a target

Comment: Let me be a little more blunt: if you are not a trained professional, **this sounds insane.  Don't do it.**

Comment: You also might want to consider not doing this after having publicly declared your intention to do it on the internet... especially as your questions on other sites give away quite a few clues about what you might look like and other biographical details

Comment: I doubt breaking of a fifth of the bar would be accepted.

Comment: @user568458 which other questions? I'm very careful.

Comment: @User I'd suggest seeing if you can de-link your Travel account from your other accounts. From about 10 minutes skimming a few random questions, they don't completely give away anything beyond what city you live and work in, what type of shop you work in, how many people you work with, your parental & marital status and your religion, but I do feel like there are enough clues that I could guess your gender, age to within 8 years, your race, how strong an accent you have, your personality... plus a couple of clues that narrow down which districts your workplace could be...

Comment: @user568458 I hope they don't send you after me Sherlock!

Comment: @user568458: Like asking if he can wear a bulletproof vest?

Comment: @User You laugh but it's not difficult to work out that you're possibly Finnish or have a connection with Finland and work and live in the UK and are probably an IT professional from just a cursory glance at your network profiles. But I honestly wonder if this question isn't a wind-up though (looking at your other posts).

Comment: @Nobilis the question is serious and valid but thanks for being polite

Comment: in the laptop bag question he shows which flight it is!

Comment: To be clear, restrictions on the import/export of cash and equivalents exist to stem money laundering.  Getting someone else to carry a gold bar for them across an international border is exactly the sort of thing a criminal might seek to do as part of a money laundering scheme.  So I’d be prepared to answer quite a few deeply probing questions from highly sceptical customs officers and, if you’re unable to answer those questions to their satisfaction, face potential criminal sanctions.

Answer (score 66):

It's allowed, I have personally seen a passenger who booked a seat for a bag. I then asked the passenger and he said it was gold. I was an operating flight attendant.

I also do not recall any rules regarding prohibiting gold onboard, (from an aviation point of view) unless it was in the shape of a knife I assume. Just check with the airline you are flying with in case they have specific rules regarding that (I don't think they would).

Finally, make sure about the customs regulations in the destination country, that's what I would worry about.

Comment: But are all forms of gold allowed? Gold coins or other small pieces may be more acceptable than a 12kg gold bar - it may be seen as something dangerous enough to be a weapon, or opaque enough to x-rays to be a risk of concealing something inside - maybe it's not gold at all but is gold plated lead with a concealed door.

Comment: I also wouldn't be surprised if it requires a separate seat due to weight requirements.

Comment: @NateEldredge Huh... Im wrong. For some reason i thought it was super heavy.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg it *is* rather dense — a gold bar is smaller than the great majority of other things weighing 12kg, at roughly 250 x 70 x 35 mm.

Comment: @Johnny the weight would mean that depending on the airline it's not allowed under its carryon regulations. That's probably the main problem you're going to face with the airline. On top of that there may be problems with customs as many countries place restrictions on the value of things you're allowed to take in or out, and there are still countries where the private possession of gold is illegal.

Comment: Whilst trying to get back some lost property at Dubai airport a few years back, and getting in conversation with the guy, he told me, _people leave all sorts of things on the planes... we even had a gold bar_

Comment: "I also do not recall any rules regarding prohibiting gold onboard, unless it was in the shape of a knife" A solid gold knife wouldn't be sharp because gold is too soft to hold an edge. The airline still wouldn't let it on board in case it was a gold-plated steel knife, which is unfortunate, since Archimedes taught us how to test that, long before the invention of the plane

Comment: @DavidRicherby even if it is not sharp, I guess you could still kill someone with that thing.

Comment: Maybe he was trolling you. If I was really carrying a gold bar, I wouldn't tell it to my fellow passengers, as a general rule.

Answer (score 39):

Anecdotally, [you can buy gold at a vending machine in Abu Dhabi airport](http://www.businessinsider.com/gold-vending-machine-abu-dhabi-2010-5?IR=T), in the outgoing terminal. **Whilst policies at destinations will vary of course, it's highly unlikely to be widely illegal whilst being sold at an airport.**

[Gold ATMs are available across the world](http://www.gold-to-go.com/en/locations/atm-locations/) - not sure I would have believed it if I hadn't seen it myself while transiting through Abu Dhabi! :)

[image]

Comment: +1 for the photo alone!  I've heard of such machines, but never actually saw one myself.

Comment: Why would anyone need some gold so bad that they need to resort to a vending machine?

Comment: I know! I can only assume it's A) novelty or b) ostentation

Comment: Really silly ... OF COURSE there are cash machines where you can withdraw a few hundred dollars of cash. But can you arrive in a country with A MILLION IN CASH?  these gold machines just sell small amounts of gold -- a few thousand dollars worth.

Comment: "it's highly unlikely to be widely illegal whilst being sold at an airport."  One would think, but a few years ago there was a controversy where whale meat (illegal to import nearly everywhere) was being sold at Reykjavik airport: http://grapevine.is/news/2011/11/04/whale-meat-sales-at-airport-stopped/

Comment: And I would expect passengers flying to India would take a hard pass.  Japan and India are a bit more serious than Russia.

Answer (score 21):

You are carrying a half-million dollars in gold on your person and you are flying into... Russia?  Keep a sharp eye out.

As Nate points out, you may have to pay an import duty in Russia, but apparently there are no restrictions on the British end.  In the US, you would have to declare it.  Last year, I got into a nasty run-in with ICE who were convinced I was exporting currency.

My research corresponds with yours: nothing about carrying metal on the plane.  I imagine getting through the security checkpoint is going to be a hassle though.  Gold is pretty impervious to x-rays.

Comment: Of *course* he/she is flying into Russia... I've heard there are Moscow nightclubs that won't let you in unless you are carrying a solid gold bar of at least 200 troy ounces  `;-)`  this question might be the most Russian (or, specifically, London to Moscow) thing I've ever read

Comment: I am living in Moscow and although i haven't heard about such a club but It's really not that scary out here. There are a lot of rich people especially who made money on corruption things with ganger past. And all this reach guys love to spend their money in here too, drinking and partying with pretty Russian girls in clubs. So my advise is to try avoid any problems with locals as most of them has crime type of connections.

Comment: [Anecdotal evidence](http://blogs.scientificamerican.com/observations/what-it-s-like-to-carry-your-nobel-prize-through-airport-security/) re hassle at the security checkpoint. Brian Schmidt's Nobel medal caused a few questions to be asked.

Answer (score 15):

Not exactly your destination, but [Werner Rydl](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Werner_Rydl) was arrested in Brazil when he was carrying a [bar of gold](http://www.midianews.com.br/conteudo.php?sid=3&cid=227877).

Also others have been [arrested](http://www.gazetadigital.com.br/conteudo/show/secao/9/materia/408090/t/homem-e-preso-com-15-kg-de-barras-de-ouro-em-aeroporto) when they were unable to promptly provide the origin of the gold they were carrying.

Since you said in some comment that you will just transport the gold but you're not the owner of it... You'd be a [mule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mule_(smuggling)), or, if you were in Brazil, [mula](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mula_(tr%C3%A1fico)).

Comment: `Mule` is the word you are looking for.