# Are there any laws that prohibit trading on the airplane?

Tags: air-travel

I mean by fellow passengers/individuals not the aircrew. Like if the person sitting next to you offers to sell you something.

Comment: Did you try to sell [your gold bar](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50882/can-i-fly-with-a-gold-bar) in the plane?

Comment: Hypothetical question, voting to close.

Comment: This would be part of the shadow economy. There is a great [Freakonomics podcast from 3 years ago this week](http://freakonomics.com/2012/08/30/how-deep-is-the-shadow-economy-a-new-freakonomics-radio-podcast/) which covers this topic indepth.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about travel but a question about laws

Comment: This is a rather hypothetical but it is unlikely that an airline that want to sell you stuff will let you sell stuff to the passengers on a flight.

Comment: Boeing officially sells their aircraft in flight. As in, the handover of the paperwork is usually done on board the aircraft during its delivery flight...

Comment: @jwenting Not sure of the relevance here but it's still the owner/lessor/lessee of the aircraft doing the selling.

Comment: Do you mean just sale or good or services as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no such restrictions on flights.

However, *for your own safety*; you should be careful and apply your normal common-sense checks, just like you would in any other transaction.

There are no specific protections provided to you, just because you are on a flight.

You would still be liable for the sale (for example, if the item is subject to customs you would be liable for that; similar to taxes, etc.).

Especially be cautious purchasing electronic items which may be [a] counterfeit [b] stolen [c] infested with malware.