# Air Canada or Delta? Which has better Bag Policy?

Tags: luggage, hand-luggage, delta-air-lines, air-canada

I'm between **Air Canada** and **Delta** (*from San Jose, USA, to Vancouver, Canada*)

The only thing that matters here for me, is the Bag Policy.

I have:

- 1 small luggage (less than 23kg)
- 1 big luggage (about 23kg)
- 1 BUBM PC and Monitor Bag (about 23kg)

I only want to have my PC bag as my Carry-On bag (as it contains the PC, Monitor, Laptop, Mic, Webcam, Mouse, and Keyboard)

The other 2 luggage can be as Checked-Bags (though, it would be great if I could have my small luggage as my second carry-on, as it contains lots of important documents)

Now, the questions are:

1. Which Airline has more space for over the head carry-on? (so that I can put my PC bag there).
2. Which Airline lets us have 2 carry-on bags? (so that I can have my small luggage next to my pc bag in the over-the-head space)
3. Am I allowed to have a Laptop Backpack to put under my seat, without an extra charge? (with that in mind that I already have Carry-On bags)

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Did you google their baggage policies? What do they say?

Comment: Keep in mind that you have to be physically able to lift your carry-on into the overhead bin - the flight attendants will typically not help with this (unless you have a disability, etc).  I know I couldn't lift 23 kg over my head.

Comment: Another factor to note is that you not only have to look at the airline's general baggage policy, but also the type of plane used for the specific flights you have in mind.  For instance, it looks like Air Canada's SJC-YVR nonstops are on CRJ-900 aircraft - these have even smaller overhead bins, and many "carry-ons" will actually be valet checked, which would defeat your goal of keeping the bag in your immediate possession throughout.

Comment: Yes Aganju, I already checked their policies and am aware of their pricing. My main purpose in asking is to get info from those with real experience with a similar situation. (Thanks Nate Eldredge for the info)

Comment: PC monitors ideally should fly in the hold in their original packaging. And no airline is going to allow a 23kg carry-on.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Delta actually [says](https://www.delta.com/content/www/en_US/traveling-with-us/baggage/during-your-trip/carry-on.html) that "No maximum weight applies to carry-on baggage" except at SIN, PEK and PVG.  And in practice, carry-on bags are normally never weighed or handled by airline employees, so they have no way to tell how much it weighs.

Comment: @NateEldredge True enough, but unless you're carrying [gold bars](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/50882/3221), a 23kg bag is quite likely going to be too large to carry on anyway.

Comment: **a 23 kg carry on**? Seriously? Why not a piano?

Answer (score 5):

Forget it.

The BUBM bag is Size: 54cm x 44cm x 52cm [according to Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07SYJ6PM6)

The carry on restrictions:

- Air Canada:

  - [Carry On](https://www.sendmybag.com/airlines/air-canada-baggage-allowance): 23 x 40 x 55 cm.
  - [Add'l carryon](https://www.sendmybag.com/airlines/air-canada-baggage-allowance):  16 x 33 x 43 cm
  - 23kg is maximum (without paying overweight) for normal luggage with economy. Number depends on ticket class
- Delta

  - [Checked](https://www.delta.com/content/www/en_US/traveling-with-us/baggage/before-your-trip/checked.html): 23kg, number depends on ticketing class.
  - [Carry On](https://www.delta.com/content/www/en_US/traveling-with-us/baggage/during-your-trip/carry-on.html): 56 x 35 x  23 cm

Your PC bag is **well** above either dimensions. It will likely not be permitted, as it is big enough that a cursory glance at it will reveal that it's to big to fit in the bins.